# Creating control array in Android

Tags: android, arrays, user-interface, user-controls, multidimensional-array

How to create a control array in Android?
How to create a multidimensional (2D) array in Android?

for buttons, edit text

also ***how can we access the elements of edit text in a 2 dimensional array***

How are multidimensional arrays created in Android? And in particular a 2 dimensional array to contain Buttons or EditText?

Also, how does one access elements of these arrays once they have been created?

Comment: What is the class name of a single control? create Array<List> of that item to create a array of controls

Comment: @CSK: Do you know how to program in Java? If you do then it's exactly the same. If you don't then learn Java before starting with Android.

Comment: m trying it with grid view n by setting click listener to each one   it  worked for imageview ,but not working on edittext............i need it for creating Sudoku table

Answer (score 0):

Look at this sample what I created:

```
Button[] buttons = new Button[10];
EditText[] textboxes = new EditText[10];

View[][] buttonsAndEditboxes = new View[2][5];

// adds 10 buttons to one-dimensional array
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   buttons[i] = new Button(this);
}

// adds 10 editexts to one-dimensional array
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   textboxes[i] = new EditText(this);
}

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
      if (i == 0) {
         // adds 5 buttons to 2D array
         buttonsAndEditboxes[i][j] = new Button(this);
      } else {
         // adds 5 edittexts to 2D array
         buttonsAndEditboxes[i][j] = new EditText(this);
      }
   }
}

// access first button from the one-dimensional array           
Button fromOneDimensionalButton = buttons[0];

// access first EditText from the one-dimensional array
EditText fromOneDimensionalEdit = textboxes[0];

// access Button from the two-dimensional array
Button fromTwoDimensionalButton = (Button) buttonsAndEditboxes[0][0];

// access EditText from the two-dimensional array
EditText fromTwoDimensionalEditText = (EditText) buttonsAndEditboxes[1][0];
```

**EDIT:**

Add some code as an example for you:

main.xml layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/test" >
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.test);

        View[][] buttonsAndEditboxes = new View[2][5];

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    // adds 5 buttons to 2D array
                    buttonsAndEditboxes[i][j] = new Button(this);
                } else {
                    // adds 5 edittexts to 2D array
                    buttonsAndEditboxes[i][j] = new EditText(this);
                    buttonsAndEditboxes[i][j].setOnClickListener(this);

                    // you need to create unique id here
                    buttonsAndEditboxes[i][j].setId(j);
                    layout.addView(buttonsAndEditboxes[i][j]);

                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case 0:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Editext0 clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        case 1:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Editext1 clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        case 2:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Editext2 clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in one activity i copied it n paste it ...forced close

Comment: yep, you need to use layout.addView too (layout is your parent view), to add those editexts and buttons to current activity. Also you need to position them programmatically.

Comment: Added some code to EDIT section in my post. There's a example that's working fine. Added xml layout file code and MainActivity file where edittexts and buttons are created and some of them are added to the linearlayout. Also onClick method that handles three editext's click events. Hope it helps!

Comment: i dunno abt seting layout using LAYOUT , parent layout,viewgroup  send mi some link ,i will study it

Comment: thnx dude................actuly  m creating tables of edit text for Sudoku game using grid layout....sudoku sheet whr we givs inputs to game creating tat sheet......thnx 4 helping ..if u gt any new idea for creating sudoku sheet plzz  tell mi ...................

Comment: in ur given program as we hd created the obj of view  we  cannot retrive text valu of edittext.. :(