# How to initialize 2d array of EditText?

Tags: android, arrays

I want to create 2d array of `EdiText`.
Below is the code for this.

I don't know what the problem is.
But the app stops unfortunately.

I placed this function `createTL()` inside `onClickListener()` of a button.
If I Click that button App stops unfortunately

```
public TableLayout createTL(int r)
{
    int c=4;
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
myTL=new TableLayout(Ybus_Activity.this);
myTL.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,   TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    myTL.setStretchAllColumns(true);
TableRow[] tr = new TableRow[r];
    EditText[][] et = new EditText[r][c];
    Arrays.fill(et, new EditText(this)); 
    Arrays.fill(tr, new TableRow(this));
for(int i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
    for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
          {
          et[i][j].setLayoutParams(params);
          et[i][j].setWidth(100);
          et[i][j].setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);
          et[i][j].setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
          et[i][j].setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance());
          et[i][j].setMaxLines(1);
          tr[i].addView(et[i][j]);
          myTL.addView(tr[i]);
          }
         }
//I already have LinearLayout named "main" under onCreate() method...
//main.addView(myTL);
return myTL;
 }
```

My LogCat:

```
02-23 00:40:19.200: D/AndroidRuntime(4488): Shutting down VM
02-23 00:40:19.210: W/dalvikvm(4488): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2e97288)
02-23 00:40:19.210: E/AndroidRuntime(4488): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-23 00:40:19.210: E/AndroidRuntime(4488): java.lang.ArrayStoreException: android.widget.EditText cannot be stored in an array of type android.widget.EditText[][]
02-23 00:40:19.210: E/AndroidRuntime(4488):     at java.util.Arrays.fill(Arrays.java:966)
02-23 00:40:19.210: E/AndroidRuntime(4488):     at com.gkn.powersystemcalc.Ybus_Activity.createTL(Ybus_Activity.java:156)
02-23 00:40:19.210: E/AndroidRuntime(4488):     at com.gkn.powersystemcalc.Ybus_Activity$2.onClick(Ybus_Activity.java:140)
02-23 00:40:19.210: E/AndroidRuntime(4488):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
02-23 00:40:19.210: E/AndroidRuntime(4488):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
02-23 00:40:19.210: E/AndroidRuntime(4488):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
02-23 00:40:19.210: E/AndroidRuntime(4488):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-23 00:40:19.210: E/AndroidRuntime(4488):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-23 00:40:19.210: E/AndroidRuntime(4488):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
02-23 00:40:19.210: E/AndroidRuntime(4488):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-23 00:40:19.210: E/AndroidRuntime(4488):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-23 00:40:19.210: E/AndroidRuntime(4488):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
02-23 00:40:19.210: E/AndroidRuntime(4488):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-23 00:40:19.210: E/AndroidRuntime(4488):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-23 00:40:19.250: W/ActivityManager(1012):   Force finishing activity com.gkn.powersystemcalc/.Ybus_Activity
02-23 00:40:19.832: W/ActivityManager(1012): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{b3d47c98 com.gkn.powersystemcalc/.Ybus_Activity}
```

Comment: Maybe create 2d array from `View` instead, as this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692498/creating-control-array-in-android) showing

Answer (score 1):

Fill doesn't work on 2D arrays.  You need to loop and fill each row.

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            et[i][j] = new EditText(this);
            et[i][j].setText("1");
            et[i][j].setWidth(50);
            tr.addView(et[i][j]);
        }
}
like this??